# Divide array to use in a pagination system

Tags: javascript

I’m currently working on trying to improve on a project from youtube that I have finished, the present amount of `hourRowElement` that are appending to the `hourlySection` is 168, I made the `splitHours` function in oder to divide the array into smaller groups that I would like to use in a Pagination system.

How would I go about in merging the two operations into one?

```js
function renderWeather({ hourly }) {
  renderHourlyWeather(hourly);
  console.log(splitHours(hourly, 6));
}


const HOUR_FORMATTER = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, { hour: "numeric" })
const hourlySection = document.querySelector("[data-hour-section]");
const hourRowTemplate = document.getElementById("hour-row-template");
function  renderHourlyWeather(hourly) {
  hourlySection.innerHTML = "";
  hourly.forEach(hour => {
    const hourRowElement = hourRowTemplate.content.cloneNode(true);
    setValue("day", DAY_FORMATTER.format(hour.timestamp), { parent: hourRowElement});
    setValue("time",HOUR_FORMATTER.format(hour.timestamp) , { parent: hourRowElement});
    hourRowElement.querySelector("[data-icon]").src = getIconUrl(hour.iconCode);
    setValue("temp", hour.temp, { parent: hourRowElement });
    setValue("precip-percent", hour.chanceOfPrecip, { parent: hourRowElement });
    setValue("fl-temp", hour.feelsLike, { parent: hourRowElement });
    setValue("wind", hour.windSpeed, { parent: hourRowElement});
    setValue("precip-amount", hour.precipAmount, { parent: hourRowElement });
    setValue("humidity", hour.humidity, { parent: hourRowElement });
    setValue("dew-point", hour.dewPoint, { parent: hourRowElement });
    hourlySection.append(hourRowElement);
  });
}
// split hours into small chunks

function splitHours(hourArray, chunkSize) {
  const results = [];
  let index = 0;
  while (index < hourArray.length) {
    results.push(hourArray.slice(index, index + chunkSize));
    index += chunkSize;
  }
  return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the renderHourlyWeather function to receive an additional parameter for chunkSize and call the splitHours function to split the hourly array into smaller chunks:

```
function renderWeather({ hourly }) {
  renderHourlyWeather(hourly, 6); // pass chunkSize as 6
}

const HOUR_FORMATTER = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, { hour: "numeric" });
const hourlySection = document.querySelector("[data-hour-section]");
const hourRowTemplate = document.getElementById("hour-row-template");

function renderHourlyWeather(hourly, chunkSize) {
  hourlySection.innerHTML = "";
  const hourChunks = splitHours(hourly, chunkSize); // split hourly into smaller chunks
  hourChunks.forEach((hourChunk) => {
    const hourChunkElement = document.createElement("div");
    hourChunkElement.classList.add("hour-chunk");
    hourChunk.forEach((hour) => {
      const hourRowElement = hourRowTemplate.content.cloneNode(true);
      setValue("day", DAY_FORMATTER.format(hour.timestamp), { parent: hourRowElement });
      setValue("time", HOUR_FORMATTER.format(hour.timestamp), { parent: hourRowElement });
      hourRowElement.querySelector("[data-icon]").src = getIconUrl(hour.iconCode);
      setValue("temp", hour.temp, { parent: hourRowElement });
      setValue("precip-percent", hour.chanceOfPrecip, { parent: hourRowElement });
      setValue("fl-temp", hour.feelsLike, { parent: hourRowElement });
      setValue("wind", hour.windSpeed, { parent: hourRowElement });
      setValue("precip-amount", hour.precipAmount, { parent: hourRowElement });
      setValue("humidity", hour.humidity, { parent: hourRowElement });
      setValue("dew-point", hour.dewPoint, { parent: hourRowElement });
      hourChunkElement.append(hourRowElement);
    });
    hourlySection.append(hourChunkElement);
  });
}
```

Comment: Would I then just have to call renderHourlyWeather on a click event for a button?

Comment: i still need some assistance with this problem